pandas equivalent to pyspark QuantileDiscretizer
I'm on a special assignment to convert a piece of pyspark code to python/pandas.
trying to find what the equivalent of pyspark QuantileDiscretizer would be in the pandas world. The closest I can find is qcut function. However, it seems it is not 100% equivalent to QuantileDiscretizer.
I did a comparison b/w those two, using 3 types of buckets - 2, 3, and 10.
inputs = [(4.0, 4.0, 4.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (3.0, 3.0, 3.0), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0),(5.0, 5.0, 5.0),(6.0, 6.0, 6.0),(8.0, 8.0, 8.0),(7.0, 7.0, 7.0),(10.0, 10.0, 10.0), (9.0, 9.0, 9.0)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(inputs, ["input1", "input2",  "input3"])

qds3 = QuantileDiscretizer(numBucketsArray=[2, 3, 10], inputCols=["input1", "input2", "input3"], outputCols=["output1", "output2", "output3"])
qds3.setHandleInvalid("skip").fit(df2).transform(df2).show()

print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>pd.qcut output:")
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
arr = np.array([4.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 7.0, 10.0, 9.0 ])
pd.qcut(arr, 2, retbins=True, labels=False)
pd.qcut(arr, 3, retbins=True, labels=False)
pd.qcut(arr, 10, retbins=True, labels=False)


It seems for bucket 3, the results are identical, but not for bucket 2 and 10. see the red and blue highlighted results in the screenshot.
Has anyone come across this before? Do you know a replacement for QuantileDiscretizer in pandas world?

QauntileDiscretizer uses an approximate algotithm and here the results doesn't look good. Try to decrease the relativeError parameter.
